# .NET Convert from string of Hex values into Unicode characters (Support different code pages)

Tags: c#, encoding, globalization, decoding

I have a string of Hex values...

```
String hexString = "8A65";
```

I need to convert this string into their Unicode equivalents. The tricky part is that I need to support different code pages and some code pages have '8A65' = one character whereas other code pages would convert it into two characters.

I have no prior knowledge of which code page I will be using until I need to perform the conversion.

I've tried all sorts of stuff such as

```
byte[] original = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(hexString);
byte[] conv= Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.GetEncoding(932), orig);
char[] chars = Encoding.GetEncoding(932).GetChars(conv);
```

Note: code page 932 is Japanese

**SOLUTION**

```
string hexString = "8A65";
int length = hexString.length;
byte[] bytes = new byte[length / 2];

for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 2)
{
    bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i, 2), 16);
}

char[] chars = Encoding.GetEncoding(932).GetChars(bytes);
```

Thank you pstrjds, you are a life saver!

Comment: What is the problem you have seen with your approach? You didn't actually ask a question here.

Comment: Could you state what is your need as a question?

Comment: This is a question and answer site. You ask questions, we answer them. The defining characteristic of a question is that it ends with a question mark ('?', ASCII code 0x3F)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the hex string to bytes (see [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa-in-c)). Passing the hex string into one of the encodings to convert it to bytes just gives you the byte equivalent of those characters. I am assuming what you want is the two bytes that the 4 character string represents, so decode the hex to bytes and then you can use the encoding on the decoded bytes to get back a string.

```
Encoding.{YourEncoding}.GetChars(hexBytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Sample {
    static public void Main(){
        var data = "8A65";
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<hex>[0-9A-F]{2})",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
        byte[] bytes = regex.Matches(data).OfType<Match>().Select(m => Convert.ToByte(m.Groups["hex"].Value,16)).ToArray();
        char[] chars = Encoding.GetEncoding(932).GetChars(bytes);
        Console.WriteLine(new String(chars));
   }
}
```