# Converting a string of ASCII into normal string C#

Tags: c#, ascii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET Convert from string of Hex values into Unicode characters (Support different code pages)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608489/net-convert-from-string-of-hex-values-into-unicode-characters-support-differen)

Looking to convert a string containing an ASCII string into text, i seem to be only be able to find System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString which converts from a Byte[] but in this circumstance I would like to be able to do it from a string.

`its a string containing ASCII hex: For example : ASCI = 47726168616D would equal Graham`

Are there any built in functions for this? help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is a normal string in C#?

Comment: @Graham Try converting string to byte[] and then apply System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString

Comment: There are not ASCII string in C#, all them are Unicode. So, where is this string coming from?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `ASCII string`? Please give an example. You can use the "edit" link below your answer to extend your question.

Comment: The question is very vague. 1) show some code 2) tell us what do you have and what do you want to have

Comment: its a string containing ASCII hex: For example : ASCI = 47726168616D would equal Graham

Comment: @JaimeOlivares - Your statement is 100% false.  You can encode a string to be ASCII, if your talking about the default encoding, then I would say your statement is at most acceptable.

Comment: @Ramhound, you are totally confused, a string is encoded into a byte array or any other binary stream. So, when it is encoded, it is not a String object anymore. The string object doesn't have an Encoding attribute, so it is always Unicode. To enlight you more, in MSDN documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe(v=vs.100).aspx) it is stated: "The string type represents a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters. string is an alias for String in the .NET Framework"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
private static string GetStringFromAsciiHex(String input)
{
    if (input.Length % 2 != 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("input");

    byte[] bytes = new byte[input.Length / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i += 2)
    {
        // Split the string into two-bytes strings which represent a hexadecimal value, and convert each value to a byte
        String hex = input.Substring(i, 2);
        bytes[i/2] = Convert.ToByte(hex, 16);                
    }

    return System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
}
```