# Windows Phone - Decode ASCII in string

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, character-encoding, windows-phone, ascii

I have ASCII encoding characters in string. Something like this:

```
%7B%22video%22%3A%7B%22JSONinfo%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A212096%2C%22title
```

How can I decode it to "normal" string? I've tried to find an answer but I find solutions for byte[] of ASCII characters and so. I have an idea that I can replace all characters that starts with % by character which they represents but I think there is better aproach. And one more thing, solution must works for windows phone. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a string of ASCII into normal string C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349753/converting-a-string-of-ascii-into-normal-string-c-sharp)

Comment: Yea, It looks that he was looking for same what I am (I didn't find this question) but there isn't best answer for this and it's `HttpUtility.UrlDecode`.

Comment: Your question isn't phrased quite correctly then.  What you have is a URL encoded string that you are trying to get the 'real' version of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HttpUtility.UrlDecode().
For example, for the string you have given, the result is "{"video":{"JSONinfo":{"id":212096,"title"

Answer (score 2):

You have may alternatives. Choose whichever works for WP

```
string s = "%7B%22video%22%3A%7B%22JSONinfo%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A212096%2C%22title";
var s1 = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(s);
var s2 = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(s);
var s3 = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(s);
```