# How to convert From Hex To Dump in C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I convert my Hex to dump to get special character like symbol but when I try to convert my "0x18" i "\u0018" this value. Can anyone give me solution regarding this matter.

Here is my code:

```
    public static string FromHexDump(string sText)
    {
        Int32 lIdx;
        string prValue ="" ;
        for (lIdx = 1; lIdx < sText.Length; lIdx += 2)
        {
            string prString = "0x" + Mid(sText, lIdx, 2);
            string prUniCode = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt64(prString,16)).ToString();
            prValue = prValue + prUniCode;
        }
        return prValue;
    }
```

I used VB language. I have a database that already encrypted text to my password and the value is `BAA37D40186D` like this so I loop it by step 2 and it will like this `0xBA,0xA3,0x7D,0x40,0x18,0x6D` and the VB result getting like this `º£}@m`

Comment: I would reconsider your approach.  Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25639044/3135317

Comment: i want to convert my hex into special characters for example like this "0xA3" = £  but when this "0x18" i got like this "\u0018"

Comment: Try adopting the example I showed you.

Comment: Could you provide some dump *examples*? Say, `"abc0x1234def"` and expected results?

Comment: @confidentialaccount .NET strings are Unicode. That's not a matter of opinion. You don't need any kind of escaping to include "special" characters in a Unicode string. `\u0018` is the C# escape sequence used to insert the *single, non printable* [Cancel Character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancel_character), a control character just like CR or LF, in a *string literal*, ie in code. The escape sequence for the pound character is `\u00A3`. Are you sure you aren't confusing the debugger's view for some non-existent escape sequence?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos hi sir. im sorry sir because im just a beginner in c# language. I used VB language. I have a database that already encrypted  text to my password and the value is "BAA37D40186D" like this so I loop it by step 2 and it will like this 0xBA,0xA3,0x7D,0x40,0x18,0x6D and the VB result getting like this º£}@m

Comment: @confidentialaccount it's no different in VB.NET. The runtime is the same, Unicode is the same, the escape sequences are the same. And the byte value that correspondes to `£` is the second one, `,0xA3`. In the string you just posted `0x18` is *invisible*. You posted 6 bytes but the string seems to contain only 5.

Comment: In any case, those bytes seem to be just the Latin1 values of the characters. You can get the string with eg `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(new byte[] {0xBA,0xA3,0x7D,0x40,0x18,0x6D}).Dump();`. 1252 is the Latin1 codepage in Windows

Comment: What is the column's type? I suspect it's a binary column (eg varbinary), but the code treated it as a string

Comment: `that already encrypted text to my password` what does that mean? Did the code generate that string instead of storing the byte buffer to the database? You're asking people to reverse what *your* code did, simply by looking at the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is unclear - what is the database column's type? Does it contain 6 bytes, or 12 characters with the hex encoding of the bytes? In any case, this has nothing to do with special characters or encodings.

First, 0x18 is the byte value of the [Cancel Character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancel_character) in the Latin 1 codepage, not the [pound sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_sign). That's 0xA3. It seems that the byte values in the question are just the Latin 1 bytes for the string in hex.

.NET strings are Unicode (UTF16LE specifically). There's no UTF8 string or Latin1 string. Encodings and codepages apply when converting *bytes* to strings or vice versa. This is done using the [Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netframework-4.8) class and eg [Encoding.GetBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?view=netframework-4.8)

In this case, this code will convert the byte to the expected string form, including the unprintable character :

```
new byte[] {0xBA,0xA3,0x7D,0x40,0x18,0x6D};
var latinEncoding=Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
var result=latinEncoding.GetString(dbBytes);
```

The result is :

```
º£}@m
```

With the Cancel character between `@` and `m`.

If the database column contains the byte values as strings :

1. it takes double the required space and
2. the hex values have to be converted back to bytes before converting to strings

The `x` format is used to convert numbers or bytes to their hex form and vice versa. For each byte value, `ToString("x")` returns the hex string.

The hex string can be produced from the original buffer with :

```
var dbBytes=new byte[] {0xBA,0xA3,0x7D,0x40,0x18,0x6D};
var hexString=String.Join("",dbBytes.Select(c=>c.ToString("x")));
```

There are many questions that show how to [parse a byte string into a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/how-can-i-convert-a-hex-string-to-a-byte-array). I'll just steal Jared Parson's LINQ answer :

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex) {
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                     .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                     .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                     .ToArray();
}
```

With that, we can parse the hex string into a byte array and convert it to the original string :

```
var bytes=StringToByteArray(hexString);
var latinEncoding=Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
var result=latinEncoding.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: My database column data type is nvarchar

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
var myHex = '\x0633';
var formattedString += string.Format(@"\x{0:x4}", (int)myHex);
```

Or you can use this code from MSDN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-between-hexadecimal-strings-and-numeric-types):

```
string hexValues = "48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 21";
string[] hexValuesSplit = hexValues.Split(' ');
foreach (string hex in hexValuesSplit)
{
    // Convert the number expressed in base-16 to an integer.
    int value = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
    // Get the character corresponding to the integral value.
    string stringValue = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(value);
    char charValue = (char)value;
    Console.WriteLine("hexadecimal value = {0}, int value = {1}, char value = {2} or {3}",
                        hex, value, stringValue, charValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all u don't need dump but Unicode, I would recomend to read about unicode/encoding etc and why this is  a problem with strings.

PS: solution : [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608489/net-convert-from-string-of-hex-values-into-unicode-characters-support-differen)